# If 'pre' is previous, 'post' is after, what is current?

Tags: word-usage

We were discussing something like pre-boss era, post-boss era. What word describes  the era where the boss is still there?

Comment: The 'boss era.'

Comment: Exactly. Why would there be a prefix to indicate nothing?

Comment: @MattE.Эллен To indicate to the reader that the writer wants to emphasize the distinction between pre, current, and post?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

***Peri-boss era***. This prefix allows you to create delightfully clear parallel construction that covers all cases:

- **pre-**, before
- **peri-**, during
- **post-**, after

Google [ [pre- post- peri-](https://www.google.com/webhp?q=pre-%20post-%20peri-) ] for examples “in the wild”. These prefixes are popular in medical terminology, such as *pre-*, *peri-*, and *post-anesthesia*.

Comment: There seemed to be some skepticism around the initial question, and it seemed a little bit niche to me when I first saw it a month or so ago, but I just wanted to mention that, now that I have this word in my toolkit, I find myself reaching for it way more often than I would have expected.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The word you might use to describe what is happening now is *current*. *Era* is rather a grand way of referring to periods with and without a boss, but I assume there is a tinge of irony in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Although it might more conventionally be expected to mean "inside the boss", there is [some support](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intra-) for the notion that you could describe this period as the "intra-boss" (during the boss) era.