# What prefix means "during"?

Tags: single-word-requests, prefixes

The prefixes "pre-" and "post-" refer to events before and after. For instance, "pre-season" and "post-season" or "pre-study" and "post-study". Is there a prefix fitting this pattern which means "during" that can fit in the form "(prefix)-season" and "(prefix)-study"? "Mid-season" and "mid-study" seems to refer to the middle point, so it does not seem like a good fit.

Comment: The mid- prefix does not exclusively refer to the midpoint of a fixed period of time.  A camera catching someone mid-sneeze, for example, is any time during the sneeze.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If 'pre' is previous, 'post' is after, what is current?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71986/if-pre-is-previous-post-is-after-what-is-current)

Comment: @MετάEd normally I'm in favour of closing questions as duplicates but the older question is closed, and if we close this one too, then no one could submit a different, or better-quality answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Both questions are general reference.

Comment: @MετάEd I don't think so, the older question was closed because the obvious answer seemed to be "current" (as suggested by Barrie England) your upvoted suggestion came a day later when it was almost too late to save the question. Your vote says that this is a duplicate, but now you're saying it's GR. I've Googled the OP's question and got *inter* and *dia* but not *peri*, *intra* nor *in-*, so there seems to be more than one acceptable answer.

Comment: I could in fact post *inter* as an answer: [*a prefix occurring in loanwords from Latin, where it meant “between,” “among,” “in the midst of,” “mutually,” “reciprocally,” “together,” “during” ( intercept; interest); on this model, used in the formation of compound words ( intercom; interdepartmental).*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inter-)

Comment: @MετάEd   I think it is a mistake to close this question as being a duplicate of a *closed* question. There should be at least one open. **P.S** I see 8 upvotes for the comment suggesting "boss era", so users voted to close the question because they believed  the best and most logical answer was: "there is no need for a prefix"!

Comment: Wouldn't "inter-" be an acceptable prefix? Merriam-Webster and others define "inter-" as "amid" or "during" such as, "interwar", meaning, during war.

Comment: @ChrisScrima No. *Inter-* means "between", not "within". *Within* is "intra-". Interwar means between the wars, not during war.

Answer (score 12):

I'm not a language expert but I think [***intra-***](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intra-) is the prefix you are looking for:

> 1a :  within *<intragalactic>*
>   b :  during *<intraday>*
>   c :  between layers of *<intradermal>*
>   <sub>source: [merriam-webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intra-)</sub>

Comment: Why do you think *intra* is the correct word?

Comment: Because of this dictionary entry: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intra-

Comment: I personally see the prefix intra- connected with movement, e.g. when I'm moving within some area - I would use "intra-" to describe it and when from one area to another - I would use "inter-". In this case I believe that "in-" fits better the response to OP question.

Answer (score 9):

It varies from word to word, depending on the specific example, but the most common prefix is *in-*, or for there to be no prefix at all:

> I can't wait for the season to start. The in-season games are so much better than the preseason ones!
>
> After a bit of pre-study work, we did some studying, and then went for post-study drinks.

Answer (score 5):

What about *peri-* as in perinatal. It does mean "around, about", and if used in a sense of time (as in perinatal) this could mean "during"

[Dictionary entry for peri-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/peri-)

Comment: See http://www.academia.edu/2364375/Distinguishing_Between_Antemortem_Perimortem_and_Postmortem_Trauma for an example.

Comment: I think precisely because it means "around" it doesn't mean "during".  Think about _perimeter_.  What's on the perimeter is not in the circle.

Comment: @JoeCorneli This is why I added "if used in a sense of time". A perimeter is clearly space, not time. There is nothing "during" a meter. Anyway, this argument holds true for all possible answers, as we humans rarely have any words or prefixes that only and exactly mean one thing.

Answer (score 4):

In medical terms, it's "preoperative," "intraoperative," and "postoperative," with "perioperative" encompassing the entire surgical process: before, during, and after (according to Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perioperative).

Comment: Actually, this answer has the same problems as skymningen's (it's almost a duplicate): Peri-op care is the care that is given before, during and after surgery.  But the article you link to mentions _intraoperative_ care (supporting the idea from Khalid Hussain's post).

Comment: @JoeCorneli, Skymningen suggested that peri- could mean during, while PtronAv explained that peri- means before, during, and after.  This answer does not appear to have any problems to me.

Answer (score 2):

What I mostly see is the mid- prefix as in mid-season.

Comment: The OP specifically says he's not looking for this prefix.

Comment: Sorry, now I see OP is looking for a term that covers the whole, overall time period.